# Two identical boxes, each has 40, I want to simulate removing matches until either box is empty using R2OpenBUGS, but keep facing issues

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs

I'm trying to run a simulation for R2OpenBUGS where I have two matchboxes and remove one at random, and I'll run the simulation around 8000 times to find the average result.

This is the model I use:

```
writeLines("
model {
  matches_box1 <- 40
  matches_box2 <- 40

  # Initialize the total matches removed
  total_matches_removed <- 0

  # Keep removing matches until one box is empty
  while (matches_box1 > 0 & matches_box2 > 0) {
    # Choose a box at random (1 or 2)
    box_chosen <- step(2)  # Randomly choose 1 or 2

    # Remove a match from the chosen box
    if (box_chosen == 1) {
      matches_box1 <- matches_box1 - 1
    } else {
      matches_box2 <- matches_box2 - 1
    }

    total_matches_removed <- total_matches_removed + 1
  }

  # Save the result
  average_matches_removed <- total_matches_removed
}
", con = "MatchesRemoval.txt")
```

And how I run the simulation

```
res <- bugs(data = NULL, inits = NULL, n.chains = 4, n.iter = 8000, n.burnin = 1000,
            parameters.to.save = c("average_matches_removed"), model.file = "MatchesRemoval.txt", DIC = FALSE, codaPkg = TRUE)
```

I keep either running into issues with: Error in datalist[[i]] : subscript out of bounds or other errors within my model.
When trying to use the model in OpenBUGS directly I get the error message:
*Sorry something went wrong in the procedure ReadHEader in module BugsRectData*

I have performed the simulation in R directly to get the average number to be 72-73 but because it doesn't account for the MCMC process, the number varies too much.

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to run a vastly simplified version

```
writeLines("
model {
  while (n_matches_box1 > 0) {
    n_matches_box1 <- n_matches_box1 - 1
    # Increment the total matches removed
    total_matches_removed <- total_matches_removed + 1
  }

  # Save the result
  average_matches_removed <- total_matches_removed
}
", con = "MatchesRemoval.txt")
```

But get told that I have the same error, Error in datalist[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I’m not familiar with `R2OpenBUGS`, but I am familiar with MCMC in general. I see no prior specification in you code and given the process you describe, I see no place for one. So I’m not sure MCMC is an appropriate technique for your problem. As you say, direct simulation works. I would stick with that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, to clarify I used the bugs function from R2OpenBUGS, to run the MCMC process using the OpenBUGS software. I have to admit I am still unfamiliar with the package and OpenBUGS as a whole. The direct simulation does indeed work, but it lacks accuracy when estimating to the 3 decimal places, I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: MCMC doesn't give you greater accuracy than direct simulation *per se*, so I think that's a red herring.  You don't say *what* you're trying to estimate to 3dp - the average number of matches removed?   You can calculate an empirical confidence interval for your parameter of interest by looking at the distribution of its simulated values.  You can reduce the width of  the CI by increasing the number of simulations.  In my experience, 8000 simply isn't enough.

Comment: Typically, estimating a proportion to within 1% using MCMC needs a chain length (kind of like a sample size) of around 40000.  You want to estimate to 3dp/sf, not just 2, so you will need massively more samples.  [The half width of a 95% CI for a binomial proportion is approximately `1.96 * sqrt(p * (1-p)/n)` and is maximised for p = 0.5].  To estimate p to within 1%, you need half width to be less than 0.5 for the percentage or 0.005 for the proportion.  It's easy to solve for n.  I get roughly 40,000 for 2sf and 4,000,000 for 3sf.